# Writing the data that comes with socat to the file

Tags: linux, bash, sockets, tcp, socat

How do I write the message I sent to the txt file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but I think you want to write the data you receive from the socket into a file, so the receiving end becomes:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:25,reuseaddr,fork OPEN:data.txt,creat,append
```

Comment: they're all shared into one file. any way to write to separate files instead (one file per client connection)?

Comment: @Eric Good question! I don't know the answer, so maybe try asking it as a new question so the regular `socat` folk see it - maybe with a link to this question and vice-versa.

Comment: the solution I've found for writing in separate files is to use `'SYSTEM:cat > filename.$$'` as destination. It will create as many file as there are connections.

Comment: This solution has strange inconsistent results for me. One time (one of the 2048 or 4096 results), the client would see the file it sent back as a response. 2 times the file ends up 4096 bytes, 2 times 0 bytes, and 2 times 2048 bytes. And just 1 time the file was the right size (24576 bytes). Doing it the `SYSTEM:cat` way always results in a 0 bytes file and the file content sent back as a response.

Comment: Tip: add `-u` to socat if you don't want to be able to read on the file. Otherwise if you try to redirect a command that doesn't end like `journalctl -f`, `dmesg -w`, ... the connection is closed before it can write anything (cc @Peter )

Comment: @Cecile that sounds like a nice redundant workaround for the strange sending data back as a response, but I don't see why it should fix the other issues. ... and apparently on a proper linux (tried 3 machines... artixlinux, ubuntu, centos), it works either way. I'll have to retest it again like last time to see if `-u` makes a difference (client end was cygwin).

Comment: @Peter I think it's not that strange. Socat does bidirectional by default so it does allow to read OR write to the file when you connect to the socket. The only reason it fails with commands that don't end is because when no output is produced, nc does receives input, and I think socat close the connection when the file is completely read.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`tee`(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) to both print to *stdout* and write to a file:

```
socat -lu STDIO TCP-LISTEN:8080,reuseaddr |tee stdout.log
```

The default logging of socat still goes to *stderr*.